# Where is mapped a strip by complex square root?

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, complex-numbers

Does the complex square root maps a strip such this
 $$\lbrace {z|a\leq \Re z\leq b, 0<\Im z<1\rbrace}$$ $a,b>0$, 
into another strip?

Comment: Into or onto? Which branch of the square root? (And how is this several-complex-variables?)

Comment: [Here is the image of the unit square](http://i.imgur.com/NY5ugFm.png) (the square $0 \leq x,y \leq 1$) under the principal branch of the square root function.

Comment: I want to know: if I have $z$ with $\Re z\in [a,b], \Im z\in (0,1)$ its principal square root is it in a strip similiar to that in the message.

Comment: @AntonioVargas: The OP doesn't seem to realize how your link is related to the question. Perhaps you could expand on that, and make it an answer.

Answer (score 2):

No, it does not. Under the square root map the horizontal line $y=c$, with $c\ne 0$ is transformed to a branch of $2uv=c$, which is a hyperbola. The vertical line $x=c$, with $c\ne 0$, is transformed to a branch of $x^2-y^2=c$, which is another hyperbola.

As a matter of fact, all lines not passing through the origin are mapped to hyperbolas.

You may notice that two families of hyperbolas given above are orthogonal; this is a consequence of the conformality of the map.